# Sonic Pi Application Open But Not Listening to 4557 Port

Tags: lxterminal, sonic-pi

I have Sonic Pi launched on my GUI desktop and am attempting to access it's local server via terminal to run some code in Sonic Pi. Whenever I attempt this the terminal tells me that Sonic Pi is not listening to 4557 and questions whether it's running. Unless I missed something big here, how do I turn on Sonic Pi to listen to 4557?